# Chunks in text Rmarkdown - Xaringan

Tags: r, r-markdown, xaringan

I am making a xaringan presentation and I am trying to show my chunk options in R Markdown, and I need that it appears in a gray square.

Like this image:

[image: Code chunk with nice gray square]

But I just get my code without that nice gray square:

[image: My code chunk without the nice gray square]

And of course I don't know how to put the highlights in this kind of code chunks. If somebody knows how to do it, I will really appreciate it.

This is the code I wrote in order to get the chunk without the square:

`````
```{r echo=FALSE, comment = NA} 
cat("````
```{r, echo = TRUE, eval=TRUE, out.width = '50%', fig.align = 'center'}`r ''`

url <- 'https://media.springernature.com/full/springer-static/\nimage/art:10.1186%2Fs13059-020-02088-y/MediaObjects/13059_2020_2088_Fig1_HTML.png'

knitr::include_graphics(url) 

```\n````")

```
`````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the example in the "Ninja" presentation template, you can produce "raw chunks" by using the `markdown` formatting with some tricks:

`````
# Test

````markdown
`r ''````{r, echo = TRUE, eval=TRUE, out.width = '50%', fig.align = 'center'}

url <- 'https://media.springernature.com/full/springer-static/\nimage/art:10.1186%2Fs13059-020-02088-y/MediaObjects/13059_2020_2088_Fig1_HTML.png'

knitr::include_graphics(url) #<<
```
````

Output:
```{r, echo = TRUE, eval=TRUE, out.width = '50%', fig.align = 'center'}

url <- 'https://media.springernature.com/full/springer-static/\nimage/art:10.1186%2Fs13059-020-02088-y/MediaObjects/13059_2020_2088_Fig1_HTML.png'

knitr::include_graphics(url) #<<
```
`````

Line highlighting is done with `#<<`. For this, you need to enable the highlighting in the yaml header (again, I've taken the default from the Ninja template):

```yaml
output:
  xaringan::moon_reader:
    lib_dir: libs
    nature:
      highlightStyle: github
      highlightLines: true
      countIncrementalSlides: false
```